# Implement tryit feature of w3schools.com for java program

Tags: java, php, html

Everyone of us is familiar with *try it yourself* online editor of **w3schools.com**.
We can execute html,css,php,javascript etc. programs in 'try it'.
I have implemented same feature in my project for java.
Program executes using php-javabridge.

When my code is

```
class generate

{

public static void main(String args[])

       {
             System.out.println("Hello World");
             System.out.println("Hi World");
       }
}
```

In output,it displays only:

```
Hi World
```

Instead,it should display:

```
Hello World
Hi World
```

When my code is

```
class generate

{

     public static void main(String args[])
       {
             System.out.print("Hello World");
             System.out.print("Hi World");
       }
}
```

In output,it displays everything:

```
Hello WorldHi World
```

What could be the possible problem behind this?Any guess?

Comment: I don't believe this. probably it is just a display error

Comment: If I call multiple functions in same program one after another,last function's result is displayed in program.For e.g,In main,I called,obj.add(a,b);obj.add(a,b,c) then result of obj.add(a,b,c) is only shown.First result is vanished.

Answer (score 0):

Solution to problem is simple.

My php program is:

require_once("javabridge/java/Java.inc");

exec('javac '.$filename,$output,$resultCode);

echo exec('java -cp . generate');

You need to do following modifications to your program.

ob_start();//solution step-Turn on output buffering

require_once("javabridge/java/Java.inc");

exec('javac '.$filename,$output,$resultCode);//$filename is generate.java,classpath current directory

echo exec('java -cp . generate',$output);//call generate.class and store output in $output

ob_end_clean();//solution step-Clean (erase) the output buffer and turn off output buffering

echo implode(delimiter,$output);//convert $output array to string and display

And finally,you get the desired result.